# Splash screen doesn't display logo : thread.execute.get()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

My splash screen syncronize my app :

When I use :

```
sd.execute("init_sync", null).get();
```

My logo (defined in xml) disappear. If I quit .get(), it appears.

Here is my code :

```
 public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private Context ctx = null;
private Usuario mUser = null;
SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ctx = this;
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Check if user exists
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonUser = prefs.getString("usuario", "");
            mUser = gson.fromJson(jsonUser, Usuario.class);

            if (NetworkUtils.isOnline(ctx)) {
                if (mUser != null) {
                    SyncData sd = new SyncData(ctx);
                    try {
                        sd.execute("init_sync", null).get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            } else {
                if (mUser != null) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, DashBoard.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Necesita Internet para loguearse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

I have several asyncTask that I use to upload pics, and sync MySQL database with my SQLite database. So, I need to wait till all the processes end to know if there is any error.

The thing is I put it in a thread, so that it would not affect UI. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @ashishduh says, I was in UI Thread. So I changed:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
@Override
        public void run() {
....
     }
}
```

by

```
Runnable sync = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
 ....
     }
};

Thread t = new Thread(sync);
t.start();
```

And it solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `get()` it causes the UI thread to wait.  Don't use `get()`.  You need to override the `onPostExecute` method in `AsyncTask`.

```
private Boolean task1Finished = false;
private Boolean task2Finished = false;
private Boolean task3Finished = false;

//...

SyncData sd1 = new SyncData(ctx) {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        task1Finished = true;
        goToNextActivity();
    }
};

SyncData sd2 = new SyncData(ctx) {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        task2Finished = true;
        goToNextActivity();
    }
};

SyncData sd3 = new SyncData(ctx) {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        task3Finished = true;
        goToNextActivity();
    }
};

try {
    sd1.execute();
    sd2.execute();
    sd3.execute();
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//...

private void goToNextActivity() {
    if (task1Finished && task2Finished && task3Finished)
        // all tasks complete
}
```

Comment: In fact, I have defined the onPostExecute, but it is not that simple, because I must wait several Async Task to be completed so that I could open next screen. But the logo of the own activity should display no???

Comment: I don't know what your logo is, but you stated that `get` is what is causing it to not appear.  If you must wait for several AsyncTasks, then you need call the next one in `onPostExecute`, or have boolean flags for each of them and check the flags in every `onPostExecute` before going to next Activity.  The AsyncTasks don't run in parallel actually.

Comment: I edited answer that will work for multiple AsyncTasks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a bit more complicated, because I don't know the number of threads... Tx for helping ! I tried to put the .get() in onStart() or onResume(), but it doesn't work :(

Comment: My question is : why is it "freezing / not displaying" if I put it in a new Thread

Comment: You're not putting it in a new thread, you're calling it from the UI thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53830/discussion-between-juliatzin-del-toro-and-ashishduh)